# Sending response from express to react using axios (backend to frontend)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm writing an application that will follow some chefs and their new recipes they post. I making a simple frontend application in which you can insert the username of the chef and it will be sent to backend which will scrape couple cooking websites to find their recipes and send it back to frontend.

When I input the name and click the button in frontend, the GET request is sent to Express.js which catches the request, grabs the username from it and begins scraping websites. I was able to do this part...I am able to scrap websites. But I can't reply back to frontend with the data I found.

This is my frontend:

```
export const FindUsername = () => {
    const usernameRef = useRef(null)
    const [ username, setUsername ] = useState('');
    const handleClick = async () => {
        setUsername(usernameRef.current.value);
        const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/user/${username}`)
            .then(res => {
                //console.log(res);
                console.log(res)
            })
        console.log(response)
    }
    return (
        <Stack direction="row">
            <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Username" variant="outlined" inputRef={usernameRef}/>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>Find User {username}</Button>
        </Stack>
    );
}
```

On the backend part I created routes which require a module.

This is the module:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');


const searchWithUsername = async (username) => {
    const targetURL = "https://www.xxxxxxx.com/profile/" + username + "/recipes";
    const {data} = await axios.get(targetURL);
    const recipes = [];
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);
    $('.css-1xwc2tk').each((index, element) => {
        const recipe = $(element).find('.recipe_title').text()
        recipes.push(recipe)
    })
    return recipes;

}

module.exports = searchWithUsername;
```

This code above takes the username passed in the `http://localhost:3001/user/${username}` field and uses axios in the backend to initate a GET request to a recipe site and cheerio to scrape it all. It then stores one example recipe in an array, for now.

Now...my idea is that the route in express can be used like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const username = req.user_config.user;
    console.log('Got body:', req.user_config.user);
    console.log(searchWithUsername(username));
    res.type('application/json')
    //res.send("OK")
    res.send(searchWithUsername(username).then());
    //res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

I use `John` as an example username. I am receiving an {} body on the frontend. On the backend, depending on testing I either get `Promise { <pending> }` or when I insert `console.log()` I get reponse on the backend terminal.

What am I doing wrong and why is this promise pending?

Comment: go grab an postman and dig into why http://localhost:3001/user/${username} fails on you. When performing preliminary testing (not real testing) you should at least go grab another tool to just test the front or backend, but not both at the same time.

Comment: I tested with Burp. It's not http://localhost:3001/user/${username} fails, that flow works. I am able to test with different usernames. The issue I had was sending the response from the backend back to frontend. I have a GET request from frontend to backend that triggers another GET request from backend to some website and I need to return that value to the first GET.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out while writing this question...

This is the code that should have been change in the route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const username = req.user_config.user;
    console.log('Got body:', req.user_config.user);
    res.type('text/plain');
    searchWithUsername(username).then(response => {
        res.send(response)
    });
});
```

First call the function `searchWithUsername(username)` with finishing the promise that sends a response back to the client.

If anybody sees something that should be fixed or changed, please share your insights. I am a beginner in these technologies.